# jQuery is not defined (using Webpack)

Tags: jquery, webpack

I have three scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script-A.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script-B.js"></script>
```

`main.min.js` is a file I create with Webpack. This file includes all the scripts I need for my project, including jQuery, which I have installed as a NPM package.

`script-A.js` and `script-B.js` are scripts that unfortunately I can't include in my main Webpack file, so I need to load them separately. These scripts need jQuery as a dependency; but even though jQuery is included in `main.min.js`, I get a `jQuery is not defined` error when they are invoked.

By the way, in my Webpack file I already have these lines of code, which let me use jQuery in any script I handle through Webpack, but it doesn't seem to have any effect on the other scripts:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    "window.jQuery": 'jquery'
})
```

How can I fix the error? Ideally, I need a solution where I don't have to touch `script-A.js` and `script-B.js` since they belong to a plugin.

**CONSOLE SNIPPET**

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at script-A.js?ver=2.9.6:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at script-B.js:617
    at script-B.js:620
```

**PACKAJGE.JSON**

```
{
  "name": "mysite",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "mysite",
  "main": "webpack.config.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "jquery-lazy": "^1.7.5",
    "salvattore": "^1.0.9",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "browser-sync": "^2.18.13",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.0",
    "url-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: can you show the console snippet?

Comment: And can you share your package.json file

Comment: @PraveshKhatri Updated my answer, thanks for looking.

Comment: Could you remove `"window.jQuery": 'jquery'`, if you are not using Angular. and just Try

Comment: I don't think there is any way to use plugins from your webpack bundle in external scripts. Maybe removing jquery from your webpack configuration and manually include jquery in your .html file will do the trick?

Comment: @PraveshKhatri Just tried, it gets worse. The error still remains and now even my custom scripts using jQuery, which were working before, are not working anymore. (I'm not using Angular by the way).

Comment: @RickvanOsta Including jQuery manually solves the external scripts issue, but then the scripts I bundle with Webpack and that need jQuery won't work, unless I also keep the jQuery npm package, but that means loading jQuery twice, which is crazy.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to make use of the [`expose-loader`](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/expose-loader/) in order to make jQuery available to the other scripts on the global scope.

```
module: {
  rules: [{
    test: require.resolve('jquery'),
    use: [{
        loader: 'expose-loader',
        options: 'jQuery'
    },{
        loader: 'expose-loader',
        options: '$'
    }]
  }]
}
```

Comment: YES! Perfect! Thank you so much!

Comment: I found adding this in the rule set:

{
                test: require.resolve("jquery"),
                loader: "expose-loader",
                options: {
                    exposes: ["$", "jQuery"],
                },
            },

Then adding

import $ from "jquery";

as the first line of my entry-point app.ts (I'm using ts-loader to transpile) helped.